# Understanding and altering the structure of posted images

Tags: functions, images

Currently this is the (default) Wordpress image output:

**Float left, with caption, link to img**

```
<figure id="attachment_10220" style="width: 167px;" class="wp-caption alignleft">
    <a href="http://link-to-my-image.jpg"><img class="wp-image-10220 size-medium" src="http://link-to-my-image-167x251.jpg" alt="" width="167" height="251"></a>
    <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">My caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Float right, without caption, link to img**

```
<a href="http://link-to-my-image.jpg" class="img-link">
    <img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-10214" src="http://link-to-my-image-257x386.jpg" alt="" width="257" height="386">
</a>
```

**Float left, without caption, no link**

```
<img class="alignleft wp-image-10218" src="http://link-to-my-image.jpg-167x251.jpg" alt="" width="167" height="251">
```

First of all I'd like to know where the output of these images is defined, what functions should I look at? My goal is to make the output more uniform:

- Wrap each image in a `figure`-tag (like the first example)
- Do not add any `style` attributes
- Add float class (alignleft, alignright) to the figure tag
- Don't output attachment (attachment_xxx) or image IDs (wp-image-xxx)
- Remove any height and width attributes from the images

Final expected output based on above examples:

```
<figure class="wp-caption alignleft">
    <a href="http://link-to-my-image.jpg">
        <img class="size-medium" src="http://link-to-my-image-167x251.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">My caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="alignright">
    <a href="http://link-to-my-image.jpg">
        <img class="size-medium" src="http://link-to-my-image-257x386.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</figure>
<figure class="alignleft">
    <img src="http://link-to-my-image.jpg-167x251.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
```

Comment: you talking about featured image output or the images add to post/page content. Featured image ouput can be easily modified with theme and `the_post_thumbnail()` function parameters.

Comment: post the url to check the structure if possible

Comment: @Vikram What do you mean by "post the url"? I can't be more clear than my example.

Comment: Paste the url of page here.

Comment: @Vikram What page. I can't be more clear than my examples so I don't see the point.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with your first code.
If you add texts, captions etc. a shortcode will be generated: `[caption]`
The function `img_caption_shortcode()` in *wp-content/media.php* is responsible to execute the shortcode. But this shortcode is only produced, when you use captions. Otherwise, it will be simply inserted the `<a>`- and `<img>`-Tag.

### who decides, what gets inserted?

There is an interesting ajax request taking place, once you add a media file: `send-attachment-to-editor`. It sends all the data like 'image-size', 'url', 'html'...

The function `wp_ajax_send_attachment_to_editor()` which can be found in *wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php* is called by this ajax request. This functions attaches the image for example to the post. More interesting for us: This function creates the HTML, which will be posted in the editor. So, here it is decided, whether the `[caption]` shortcode or a simple `<img>`-Tag will be used.

### The filter media_send_to_editor

Good for us since `wp_ajax_send_attachment_to_editor()` uses the filter `media_send_to_editor` to give us the chance to alter this code. Three parameters are given:
 - the current HTML output
 - the Attachment ID
 - the information, how big the image is, the align...

Just as an example:

```
 add_filter( 'media_send_to_editor', 'test_media', 10, 3 );
 function test_media( $html, $id, $attachment ){
    return '<a href="http://example.com">TEST</a>';
 }
```

This would always print the Link http://example.com/

I hope this helps you as a start.

### A "better" shortcode

To receive now the output, you want, I would suggest the following:

```
<?php
  add_filter( 'media_send_to_editor', 'use_always_caption', 10, 3 );
     function use_always_caption( $html, $id, $attachment ){
        $post = get_post( $id );
        //Return if its not an image
        if ( 'image' != substr( $post->post_mime_type, 0, 5 ) )
            return $html;
        $rel = '';
        $url =  isset( $attachment['url'] ) ? $attachment['url'] : '';

        if ( strpos( $url, 'attachment_id') || get_attachment_link( $id ) == $url )
            $rel = ' rel="attachment"';

        $align = isset( $attachment['align'] ) ? $attachment['align'] : 'none';
        $size = isset( $attachment['image-size'] ) ? $attachment['image-size'] : 'medium';
        $alt = isset( $attachment['image_alt'] ) ? $attachment['image_alt'] : '';
        $caption = ' ';
        if( isset( $attachment['post_excerpt'] ) && ! empty( $attachment['post_excerpt'] ) )
            $caption = $attachment['post_excerpt'];
        $title = ''; // We no longer insert title tags into <img> tags, as they are redundant.
        add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 'remove_id_from_class_and_hw', 10, 6 );
        $html = get_image_send_to_editor( $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, (bool) $rel, $size, $alt );
        remove_filter( 'get_image_tag', 'remove_id_from_class_and_hw', 10, 6 );
        $html = preg_replace( '^toremove--width="(.*)"--toremove^', '', $html );
        return $html;
     }

     function remove_id_from_class_and_hw( $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ){
         list( $img_src, $width, $height ) = image_downsize( $id, $size );
         $class = 'align' . esc_attr( $align ) .' size-' . esc_attr( $size );
         return '<img src="' . esc_attr( $img_src ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $alt ) . '" ' . $title . ' class="' . $class . '" toremove--width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"--toremove />';
     }

     remove_shortcode( 'caption' );
     add_shortcode( 'caption', 'better_img_caption_shortcode' );
     function better_img_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content = null ){
        if ( ! isset( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
            if ( preg_match( '#((?:<a [^>]+>\s*)?<img [^>]+>(?:\s*</a>)?)(.*)#is', $content, $matches ) ) {
                $content = $matches[1];
                $attr['caption'] = trim( $matches[2] );
            }
        }

        $output = apply_filters( 'img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content );
        if ( $output != '' )
            return $output;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id'      => '',
            'align'   => 'alignnone',
            'width'   => '',
            'caption' => '',
            'class'   => '',
        ), $attr, 'caption' );

        $atts['width'] = (int) $atts['width'];
        if ( $atts['width'] < 1 )
            return $content;

        $class = trim( 'wp-caption ' . $atts['align'] . ' ' . $atts['class'] );

        $figcaption = '';
        if( ! empty( $atts['caption'] ) )
            $figcaption = '<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">' . $atts['caption'] . '</figcaption>';
        return '<figure class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">'
            . do_shortcode( $content ) . $figcaption . '</figure>';

     }
?>
```

I've copy-pasted a bit :)

So, what I do: With the filter `media_send_to_editor` I force WordPress to always use the `[caption]`-Shortcode. We alter a bit the image output by using the filter `get_image_tag` which is used by the function `get_image_tag()` to create the `<img>`-Tag. This function can be found in *wp-include/media.php*. Since I didn't wanted to create the whole shortcode and leave WordPress to do it, I needed to leave the width and height (you should leave it anyway, i think) because the caption creation done by `image_add_caption()` ( to be found in *wp-admin/includes/media.php*) needs these values from the string. I added an ugly `toremove--` and remove it later on.

In a second step, I remove the existing `[caption]`-Shortcode and overwrite it with my own. My own is basically the same, but I removed the ID- and the Style-Attribute. I stick to the `[caption]`-Shortcode, so once the user disables the plugin, the pictures would still show up in a reasonable way.

### Docs:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_send_attachment_to_editor/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_send_to_editor/

Comment: Hi there, so I got around to testing this and the first part works as expected: the unnecessary classes and such are removed! A big problem, however, is that there is no `figure` wrapper to the elements (see my examples above). Even when I add a caption, the figure-tags don't output, nor the caption itself. It's left out. Subsequently the align classes are nowhere to be found either.

Comment: Just letting you know that the bounty will end tomorrow but that your current answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: hi bram! the [caption] shortcode is not placed in the editor or the [caption] is not executed correctly? I just tried it again and it works for me

Comment: Well I simply used the code under "A better shortcode" in my functions.php and expected things to work by themselves. As I commented, the output of a `figure` tag and the `figcaption` tag doesn't work unfortunately.